# How to apply random color?

Tags: java, colors

The following code consist of method that is overridden to make pattern of rectangle. I wanted to give different color to each rectangle. Do you have any idea how this can be done ?

```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        int x1 = 60;
        int y1 = 60;
        int width = 280;
        int length = 140;

        Graphics paper = panelForBackGround.getGraphics();
        for (int x = 1; x < 8; x++) {

            paper.draw3DRect(x1, y1, width,length, true);
            x1 = x1 + 10;
            y1 = y1 + 10;
            width = width - 20;
            length = length - 20;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Colors can be created using RGB values. Create three random numbers between 0 and 255 (boundaries included) and apply the resulting color to your rectangle.

Comment: which class and method should I use. I started with java a week ago.

Answer (score 0):

At top of file:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Color;
```

At top of method:

```
Random random = new Random();
```

In loop before you draw:

```
paper.setColor(new Color(random.nextInt()));
```

References:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html
- [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int%29)
- [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor(java.awt.Color)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setColor%28java.awt.Color%29)

Comment: Thanks , it's working but may I know what do these three lines do ?

Comment: There is that thing called Javadoc, which contains documentation on what classes and methods do... one of *the key* skills a programmer needs is the diligence to work trough existing documentation.